# How to connect to Twitter with API 1.1 possibly using OAuth authentication?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, oauth, arduino

I have made a website + a project in Arduino that both fetches tweets from my own [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) account and acts according to these. Today the Twitter API changed to version 1.1 and now my website doesn't work.

On my website I have been using JavaScript with this code:

```
var twitter_api_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json';" 
$.getJSON( twitter_api_url  + '?callback=?&rpp=5&q=from:' + twitter_user, function(data) { ".
```

This is not working, and I don't know how to change it.

In Arduino I call:

```
client.println("GET /1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=MYTWITTER HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host:api.twitter.com");
client.println("Connection:close");
client.println();
```

I get error message 410 (gone) and "The Twitter REST API v1 will soon stop functioning. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview".

I have tried searching for fixes, but I can't find the correct solution. Might I need to make an [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) authentication? I found a guide to create parameters for this, *[generate Twitter applications keys](http://www.slideshare.net/Tweetganic/generate-twitter-applications)*, but I don't know how to add the parameters to JavaScript or Arduino code.

I found a suggestion for Arduino:

```
client.print(F("GET /1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=MYTWITTER HTTP/1.1"));
client.print(F("HOST: api.twitter.com"));
client.print(F("Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"XXX\", oauth_nonce=\"XXX\", oauth_signature=\"XXX\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1361444134\", oauth_token=\"XXX\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""));
client.println();
client.println();
```

But what is `oauth_nonce`, `oauth_signature` and `oauth_timestamp` supposed to be? Another user also replied that this didn't work, so I don't know if I want to continue with it.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you with your problem. Authenticating a User Timeline for Twitter OAuth API V1.1 > http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like a valid solution. The server I am uploading to doesn't support php though, so unfortunately I couldn't use it.

Comment: How would a php library help to use oauth for an Arduino?